# How could I integrate executors here? Or how could I improve this threading pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

Currently I have a construct that does the following:
An `X` number of threads (`X` being a configurable variable from the user) are all started and await for a task to become available. The threads `block` waiting in 
a `BlockingQueue`.
Another thread(s) places task(s) in the blocking queue and the blocked threads take the task(s) and `run` them and go back to `wait` for the next task.
Anyway this works fine but I have the following issue. `X` threads are constantly waiting for a task even if there isn't any for 2 hours.
Also `X` threads are actually available even if there are only lets'say X/50 tasks coming in (i.e. I have much more threads than I actually need).
So my question is, how could I refactor this (perhaps using `Executors`) so that `X` goes up and down as needed?
My aim is not to lose performance. I mean now I could have more threads than I would need (wasting resources) but I don't have the overhead of creating new threads.
I am interested in refactoring this in a way to not waste resources and keep the same performance levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) should suffice. The basic constructor takes parameters for "core pool size" (minimum amount of threads to keep alive at all times), maximum size (maximum amount of threads) and the keep alive time of excess threads (idle threads above core pool size). Also, you can pass your BlockingQueue straight for the executor.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Try using the `CachedThreadPool` , which will **not only recycle but create new threads when needed..**

**2.** And the **most awesome feature** of `CachedThreadPool` is that **when a thread is not active for 60 seconds its killed.... So no wastage of resources.**

Comment: Depending on what the OP is doing, he might need to put a limit on the maximum number of threads

Comment: But how do I integrate this? In `CachedThreadPool` you submit `Runnables` right? Now I have `Threads` that await in a queue. How would I go from the one design to the other?

Answer (score 0):

your usecase is already implemented in ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPoolExecutor. Anyways, i you want to go ahead with the implementation you can do various things to get a flexible thread pool.

I will list one such possibility

1. Write a Master-thread which holds the queue and assigns work unit (tasks) to various threads, Also it maintains which threads are running, which have returned the result unit and which threads are blocked. Using this information your Master-thread can easily load balance and create/destroy threads(slaves) when needed.